# Setting a variable (x) equal to a string read from a text file then using x in a conditional if statement

Tags: python

So I'm currently testing a python code that reads a text file line by line and sets a variable x_1 equal to the line being read per loop iteration. After the line is read and x_1 is set to said line, I then try to run an if statement where if x_1 is equal to a specific string found in the text file it then proceeds to do an action.

```
with open("Script2.txt") as myfile: #reads Script2.txt 
    line = myfile.readline()        #reads Script2 line by line
    while line:
        line = myfile.readline()
        x_1 = line
        print (x_1)
        if x_1 == 'Button.left True':
                cnt = cnt + 1
                print (cnt)
        else:
            break
```

However when I run this code I get this as an output:

[image: Terminal output]

The text file Script2 only contains this string: [textfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWjyz.png)

Comment: You're not using the first line !! also do  `x_1 = line.rstrip()` to remove the newline \n

Comment: You're skipping the first line.

Comment: It seems like x_1 has trailing newline characters, that's why the equality check is failing

Comment: @MateenUlhaq  why is it being skipped?

Comment: Line 2 is reading a line but then you don't do anything further with it. Also, as the other comments said, line 4 should be `line = myfile.readline().rstrip("\n")`.

Comment: A `for` loop would be simpler.

Comment: Note that `break` exits an inner `while` loop and then the end of the outer `while` loop is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should correct the code to the following:

```
cnt = 0
with open("Script2.txt") as myfile:
    line = myfile.readline()
    while line:
        x_1 = line.rstrip()
        print(x_1)
        if x_1 == """'Button.left True'""":
                cnt = cnt + 1
                print(cnt)
        else:
            break
        line = myfile.readline()
```

There were couple of things:

1. You didnt initiated the `cnt` variable
2. you read the line with the newline char `\n`
3. You skipped the first line because you read the next line in the start of the loop; So because you read a line before the loop and another one when you enter the loop the first one is skipped
4. You compared it to a wrong string, it should be `"""'Button.left True'"""`

Comment: probably         if x_1 == """'Button.left True'""":

Comment: @Boying You are right, I didnt notice there were extra `'` in the pic of the text

Comment: @boying thanks this was part of the problem, in the text file it was written as 'Button.left True' rather than just Button.left True without the quotations

Comment: @DavidS thank you, combining this with Boying's comment allowed to code to run properly